# is it Possible to use Lists to Store Listbox data , Tkinter

Tags: python, list, tkinter, listbox

I want to store it in a List so when I close program and run it back , its gonna be there.

I know this code is wrong but I couldn't find a way to store `Listbox` Data

```
from tkinter import * 
ex = []
def insert() : 
     ex.append(entry.get())
     for i in ex : 
          listbox.insert(listbox.size(),ex)

window= Tk()
listbox= Listbox(window)
listbox.pack()
button = Button(window,text="insert",command=insert)
button.pack()
entry= Entry(window,width=15)
entry.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can save it to a text file

Comment: i'll try , Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following code would suit your needs in terms of saving entry values somewhere as a list.

```
from tkinter import Entry, Tk, Button, StringVar

Root = Tk() 
EntryValue = StringVar() 
file = open ('List.txt', 'w+')

def insert():
    with open ('List.txt', 'a') as file:
        file.write('\n'+ EntryValue.get())
        file.close

class GUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.bind("<Escape>", lambda x : Root.destroy())
        master.entry = Entry(Root, textvariable=EntryValue)
        master.entry.pack()
        master.button = Button(Root,text="insert",command=insert)
        master.button.pack()

def main():
    GUI(Root)
    Root.mainloop()

main()
```

The following code will work for reading the values from the .txt file, but it's up to you how you'd like to view those values in the UI, eg a Combobox.

```
with open('List.txt') as inFile:
    ListValues = [line for line in inFile]
    ListValues = sorted(ListValues)
```